# How to write fast Nginx rules

Tags: redirect, ssl, nginx

I have NginX server running on my machine serving a bunch of websites. I'd like to handle the following cases:

- When `www` and **has certificate** then *redirect to* https://website.com/
- When `non-www` and **has certificate** then *open* https://website.com/
- When `www` and **doesn't have certificate** then *redirect to* http://website.com/
- When `non-www` and **doesn't have certificate** then *open* http://website.com/

What if someone hits `httpS://no-certificate.website.com`? How to handle such case?

My redirect rule looks like:

```
server {
  listen 80{% if not subdomain %} default_server deferred{% endif %};
  listen 443 ssl;

  server_name www.{{ webserver_name }};

{% if ssl | default(false) %}
  return 301 https://{{ webserver_name }}$request_uri;
{% else %}
  return 301 http://{{ webserver_name }}$request_uri;
{% endif %}
}
```

and then:

```
{% if ssl | default(false) %}
  listen 443 ssl;
  # ssl_certificate stuff
{% else %}
  listen 80;
{% endif %}
  server_name {{ webserver_name }};
```

What am I missing yet?

Comment: what is the reason to redirect to HTTP/HTTPS? do you use HTTPS for premium users?

Comment: I want to secure my connection.

Comment: so what not to use HTTPS everywhere?

Comment: Because I don't have wildcard SSL certificate, right now I can secure only top domain, while subdomains remains accessible over `http`.

Comment: wildcard for 1/year $65 (https://www.gogetssl.com/wildcard-ssl-certificates/)

Comment: Yep, that's right. But it's only academic project, so one SSL certificate for free is enough.